# Is there a way to add a method to System.out called printlnx that would prefix output with a string?

Tags: java, console-application, static-methods

Is there a way to add a method to System.out called printlnx that would prefix output with a string?

So, if I called :

```
System.out.printlnx("This is a test");
```

That it would print that with a prefix (specified by me) :

```
-prefix-->This is a test
```

NOTE: My intention is to mark all output from a console program so that its output appears distinct from a secondary console program that I run afterwards.

Comment: I will try the suggestions below and mark the best answer soon.  Thanks to all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  `System.out` is actually an object of type `PrintStream`.  You can't retrospectively add arbitrary methods to a particular object.

But you can very easily write one that lives in your own namespace:

```
public final class utils {
    public static void printlnx(String str) {
        System.out.println("-prefix-->" + str);
    }
}
```

Then elsewhere:

```
...

utils.printlnx("This is a test");
```

Comment: And luckily someone had the good sense to make sure that the object is final (although I actually looked that up in the src code - what an interesting way to introduce strange bugs that would've been)

Answer (score 1):

You can't add method to existing class. At least not without signifficant effort which would be pretty pointless in this case. You have two options. One is to have your own utility method as described in other answer.

Other option is to make a wrapper PrintStream around existing System.out to prefix every line and reassign it via System.setOut() method. You can even put there your own method but you will have to cast:

```
((MyPrintStream)System.out).printlnx(...)
```

---

Here is complete example that I verified to work:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        System.setOut(new MyPrintStream());
        ((MyPrintStream)System.out).printlnx("Hello");
    }

    private static class MyPrintStream extends PrintStream {

        public MyPrintStream() {
            super(System.out);
        }

        public void printlnx(String str) {
           super.println("prefix: " + str);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Oli It surely does. I added full example. Feel free to verify. It works for me.

Comment: Ah, I missed the crucial words "reassign it via System.setOut".  I agree, this should indeed work!

Comment: That being the case, would it be fair to say that you could simply override the various overloads of `println` in `MyPrintStream`, thus avoiding the need to cast everytime?

Comment: @Oli Absolutelly. That was first thing that I thought about. That will, of course, affect every print statement. Cast is interesting from pure academic standpoint. I'd rather use what you suggested in your answer anyway.